# jQuery on click run functions inside twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to run all functions twice on click function?

Example:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    function1();
    function2();
});
```

This should run `function1(); function2();` and again `function1(); function2();`

Comment: May I know the use case, there might be better way to achieve the same

Comment: Running same function twice??? That sounds like XY problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind events twice and if you want to run that function more than twice then the most preferred way is looping.

```
function twice(){
    function1();
    function2();
}

$('a').click(twice).click(twice);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wszgup9z/)

Comment: What could be the use case??? If really need to call some functions twice, then just wrap it inside other function which call them twice and bind this function

Comment: there are multiple functions and tryed to fix it - so I had no choice only to run it twice.

Comment: @Adrian can you add [mcve], why you need to call twice